# how to read json file using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a json file in the same directory where my ansible script is. Following is the content of json file:

```
{ "resources":[
           {"name":"package1", "downloadURL":"path-to-file1" },
           {"name":"package2", "downloadURL": "path-to-file2"}
   ]
}
```

I am trying to to download these packages using get_url. Following is the approach:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    package_dir: "/var/opt/"
    version_file: "{{lookup('file','/home/shasha/devOps/tests/packageFile.json')}}"

  tasks:
    - name: Printing the file.
      debug: msg="{{version_file}}"

    - name: Downloading the packages.
      get_url: url="{{item.downloadURL}}" dest="{{package_dir}}" mode=0777
      with_items: version_file.resources
```

The first task is printing the content of the file correctly but in the second task, I am getting the following error:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Skipping task due to undefined attribute, in the future this
will be a fatal error.. This feature will be removed in a future release. Deprecation
warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
```

Comment: It works for me in 2.0.0.2. What ansible version do you use?

Comment: the version is  2.1.0

Comment: Looks like there is some problem in json file. For few files it is working and for few its not.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to add a [`from_json`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/from_json_filter.html) jinja2 filter after the lookup:

```
version_file: "{{ lookup('file','/home/shasha/devOps/tests/packageFile.json') | from_json }}"
```

Answer (score 16):

In case if you need to read a `JSON` formatted text and store it as a variable, it can be also handled by [`include_vars`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html) .

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: variable-file.json
        name: variable

    - debug: var=variable
```

Answer (score 9):

for future visitors , if you are looking for a remote json file read. this won't work
as ansible lookups are executed in the local

you should use a module like [Slurp](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html)

Comment: Thanks for that - saved me a bit of reading!

Comment: For use with slurp.. `register: version_file_data` and then `{{ version_file_data['content'] | b64decode | from_json }}`. Just adding this for people's convenience.